# Follower not using her skill set?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My follower 'Jordis the Sword-Maiden' is supposedly fully maxed out in terms of her skills set, and has reached level 50, but I've noticed her perks are not in effect. She is currently equipped with full Daedric armor, and dying almost effortless by upper level enemies, such as bandit marauders.

I have tried using the Wabbajack numerous times, to reset her stats, and it is of no use. I have also noticed that her equipment is slightly greyed out whenever I try to trade her items, and this problem is also not responsive with the use of the Wabbajack, either.

What can I do to reset Jordis the Sword-Maiden, so she will use her skills? I am playing on Xbox 360.

Comment: What platform are you playing on? And if playing on the PC, can you list the mods you have installed, if you have any? What perks aren't in effect?

Comment: I'm playing on xbox, I apologize for not specifying.

Comment: I see. Also, what perks are not taking effect?

Comment: @galacticninja I'm assuming everything because I performed the shout Disarm on her and it said she was too powerful which would mean she has met her level cap or come exceedingly close. She's on her knees when facing strong level enemies such as a Warmonger, Volikhar Vampires, Bandit Chiefs, etc.

Comment: Any chance you accidentally hit her with the Marked For Death shout?

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong, but I believe that followers only have skills that bethesda sets for them, some people don't have any at all, don't quote me on that though.